I'm retrieving a response from Mockoon, but when I use return ResponseEntity, I'm getting null
I'm encountering an issue where, after retrieving a response from Mockoon, upon returning it using the ResponseEntity object, I receive a null value instead of the expected response. This issue occurs despite successfully obtaining a response from Mockoon. It seems to arise specifically when attempting to return the response using the ResponseEntity class, but I'm unsure why this is resulting in a null value. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated."enter image description here dont understant the body is correct no error enter image description here
I've checked the body of the response, and I've also debugged the code, but I can't identify the source of the problem. Everything seems to be functioning correctly; it successfully retrieves the response. However, when it reaches the point of returning the ResponseEntity, it somehow gets stuck or fails to proceed. I'm unable to determine the cause of this issue despite thorough inspection and debugging. It could possibly be a configuration issue within Mockoon

There is some info missing to help you: your Spring code returning the ResponseEntity, for example, the body template your are serving with Mockoon, the response returned by Mockoon, etc.
The error you see in Mockoon means that the request's JSON is malformed and cannot be parsed. It's usually not an issue unless you want to reuse the request in the response body.
I suggest you use curl or another tool to call Mockoon and see if the response is ok. Then you can tell if it's coming from your Java code or not.
